# Регулярное выражение как произвести поиск тега <script> по совпадению?

Tags: php

подскажите пожалуйста, как вытащить из string все совпадения по тегу script? Делаю вот так, но не получается:

```
<?php

$html = '<script>var test = 'asdsdasdasad';</script><script>var asd = 'dsadsadsasdadsa';</script>';

preg_match_all('<script>var test = (.*?)<\/script>', $html, $scripts);

var_dump($scripts);
```

Мне нужно из $html вытащить только: `<script>var test = 'asdsdasdasad';</script>`

Comment: А что значит "не получается"? Какой смысл  вкладываете в это понятие?

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли `//` в регулярном выражении. Паттерн всегда начинается и всегда заканчивается опознавательным знаком, как правило это слэш. Плюс ещё одни скобки нужны, вроде как

```
<?php
$html = "<script>var test = 'asdsdasdasad';</script><script>var asd = 'dsadsadsasdadsa';</script>";

preg_match_all('/(<script>var test = (.*?)<\/script>)/', $html, $scripts);

var_dump($scripts);


array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(43) "<script>var test = 'asdsdasdasad';</script>"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(43) "<script>var test = 'asdsdasdasad';</script>"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "'asdsdasdasad';"
  }
}
```

Вообще [парсить *html* регуляркой не самая лучшая идея](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6104996). Для этого нужно использовать библиотеку работы с html, dom, например https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.simplexml.php  или https://www.php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php